# Trying to use/include/compile 3rd party library, libmagic. C/C++ filetype detection

Tags: c++, c, include, file-type

After looking for a way to detect the filetype of a file stream, I found that the Unix [file command](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/) uses libmagic and I'm trying to make use of the library myself, but I can't get it to work. I've rarely integrated 3rd party code in my own, so that's probably a big part of my problem as well.

**Why:**

I'm doing this because I have a portable gui image viewing app that will need to detect archive file types (rar, zip, more?) from given filename and then the image file types inside. I'm hoping that I can use libmagic for Windows and Linux (and Mac), so if this isn't the case, stop me now b/c I'll need to find something else.

**Attempt:**

I found [somebody doing something similar](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-file-type-of-a-given-file-626280/), but I can't follow what they're doing, and I've no idea how compile/run anything at all to start messing around.

My first instinct was to do something like:

```
// fileTypeTest.cpp, placed in file-5.03/src/ (source from link above)
#include <stdio.h>
#include "magic.h"
int main() {
  magic_t myt = magic_open(MAGIC_CONTINUE|MAGIC_ERROR/*|MAGIC_DEBUG*/|MAGIC_MIME);
  magic_load(myt,NULL);
  printf("magic output: '%s'\n",magic_file(myt,__FILE__));
  magic_close(myt);

  return 0;
}
```

then compile with something like:

```
$ gcc magic.c -o magic.o
$ g++ fileTypeTest.cpp -o fileTypeTest magic.o
```

which (obviously?) doesn't work. I don't even know where to start looking, what questions to ask, or if this is the right direction to go to solve my original problem in the first place.

---

Edit: Now I have

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <magic.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("bad arguments");
    return 0;
  }
  magic_t myt = magic_open(MAGIC_CONTINUE|MAGIC_ERROR/*|MAGIC_DEBUG*/|MAGIC_MIME);
  magic_load(myt,NULL);
  printf("magic output: '%s'\n", magic_file(myt, argv[1]));
  magic_close(myt);

  return 0;
}
```

compiling with:

```
$ g++ -L/usr/lib -libmagic fileTypeTest.cpp -o fileTypeTest
```

works. I had to go to synaptic and install libmagic-dev though. I'll have to test to see if I can just copy /usr/lib/libmagic.a into my source directory when compiling my app on Windows's MingW, but that'll be for another question later, I suppose.

Comment: Posting the error messages you are getting would be a start.

Comment: sorry for worry, have you found this library for Windows?

Comment: yes, surely you've found it http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__FILE__` is a reserved pre-processing symbol macro used for debugging/logging purposes. Consider this as an example:

```
// This file is called test.c
char *p = NULL;
if (!(p = malloc((1 * sizeof(char) + 1)))){
   printf("Error in file: %s @ line %d\n\tMalloc failed\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
   exit(-1);
}
```

If the call to `malloc` failed you will see the output in the above example like this:

```
Error in file: test.c @ line 23
       Malloc failed
```

Notice how the code picks up the original source code. The above example illustrates the usage of this.

I think your code should be something like this:

```
// fileTypeTest.cpp, placed in file-5.03/src/ (source from link above)
#include <stdio.h>
#include "magic.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc > 1){
     magic_t myt = magic_open(MAGIC_CONTINUE|MAGIC_ERROR/*|MAGIC_DEBUG*/|MAGIC_MIME);
     magic_load(myt,NULL);
     printf("magic output: '%s'\n",magic_file(myt,argv[1]));
     magic_close(myt);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The code above checks if there is a parameter that is passed into this program and the parameter would be a filename, i.e. `argv[0]` points to the executable name (the compiled binary), `argv[1]` points to the array of chars (a string) indicating the filename in question.

To compile it:

```
g++ -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib/libmagic.so  fileTestType.cpp -o fileTestType
g++ -L/usr/lib -lmagic fileTestType.cpp -o fileTestType
```

**Edit:** *Thanks **Alok** for pointing out the error here...*

If you are not sure where the libmagic reside, look for it in the /usr/local/lib, and /usr/local/include - this depends on your installation.

See this to find the predefined macros [here](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.7.html#macros).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: He might be testing things out, so he decided to find the mime-type of the source file itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think the above "obviously" doesn't work.  See [*How to mix C and C++*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/index.html) for details.

Looks like `magic.h` has proper `extern "C" {` `}` enclosures.  So, compiling your code with `g++` should work nicely.  You can `#include <magic.h>` in your `.cpp` file, and use all the libmagic functions.

- Is there a particular error you're getting?
- I have not checked your use of the libmagic functions.
- You need to link with libmagic.  Your `g++` command needs `-lmagic`.
- Since `magic.h` is most likely in a standard place, you should use `#include <magic.h>`.

Tell us what your error is for more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `magic.h` in the filesystem? Is the preprocessor finding it? If not, use `-I<path>`.