# Compiling libmagic statically (c/c++ file type detection)

Tags: c++, compilation, libmagic

Thanks to the guys that helped me with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105816/trying-to-use-include-compile-3rd-party-library-libmagic-c-c-filetype-detecti) (linked just for reference).

I can place the files `fileTypeTest.cpp`, `libmagic.a`, and `magic` in a directory, and I can compile with `g++ -lmagic fileTypeTest.cpp fileTypeTest`. Later, I'll be testing to see if it runs in Windows compiled with MinGW.

I'm planning on using [libmagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmagic/) in a small GUI application, and I'd like to compile it statically for distribution. My problem is that `libmagic` seems to require the external file, `magic`. (I'm actually using my own shortened and compiled version, magic_short.mgc, but I digress.)

A hacky solution would be to code the file into the application, creating (and deleting) the external file as needed. How can I avoid this?

added for clarity:

`magic` is a text file that describes properties of different filetypes. When asked to identify a file, `libmagic` searches through `magic`. There is a compiled version, `magic.mgc` that works faster. My application only needs to identify a handful of filetypes before deciding what to do with them, so I'll be using my own `magic_short` file to create `magic_short.mgc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tricky, I suppose you could do it this way... by the way, I have downloaded the libmagic source and looking at it...

There's a function in there called `magic_read_entries` within the `minifile.c` (this is the pure vanilla source that I downloaded from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmagic) where it is reading from the external file.

You could append the `magic` file (which is found in the /etc directory) to the end of the library code, like this `cat magic >> libmagic.a`. In my system, `magic` is 474443 bytes, `libmagic.a` is 38588 bytes.

In the `magic.c` file, you would need to change the `magichandle_t* magic_init(unsigned flags)` function, at the end of the function, add the line `magic_read_entries` and modify the function itself to read at the offset of the library itself to pull in the data, treat it as a pointer to pointer to char's (char **) and use that instead of reading from the file. Since you know where the offset is to the library data for reading, that should not be difficult.

Now the function `magic_read_entries` will no longer be used, as it is not going to be read from a file anymore. The function `magichandle_t* magic_init(unsigned flags)' will take care of loading the entries and you should be ok there.

If you need further help, let me know,

**Edit:**
I have used the old 'libmagic' from sourceforge.net and here is what I did:

1. Extracted the downloaded archive into my home directory, ungzipping/untarring the archive will create a folder called *libmagic*.
2. Create a folder within libmagic and call it *Test*
3. Copy the original **magic.c** and **minifile.c** into *Test*
4. Using the enclosed diff output highlighting the difference, apply it onto the *magic.c* source.

```
48a49,51
> #define MAGIC_DATA_OFFSET     0x971C
> #define MAGIC_STAT_LIB_NAME "libmagic.a"
>
125a129,130
>       /* magic_read_entries is obsolete... */
>       magic_read_entries(mh, MAGIC_STAT_LIB_NAME);
251c256,262
<
---
>
>       if (!fseek(fp, MAGIC_DATA_OFFSET, SEEK_SET)){
>               if (ftell(fp) != MAGIC_DATA_OFFSET) return 0;
>       }else{
>               return 0;
>       }
>
```

- Then issue ***make***
- The magic file (which I copied from /etc, under Slackware Linux 12.2) is concatenated to the libmagic.a file, i.e. `cat magic >> libmagic.a`. The SHA checksum for magic is (4abf536f2ada050ce945fbba796564342d6c9a61  magic), 
  here's the exact data for magic 
  (-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 474443 2007-06-03 00:52 /etc/file/magic) as found on my system.
- Here's the diff for the *minifile.c* source, apply it and rebuild minifile executable by running ***make*** again.

```
40c40
<       magic_read_entries(mh,"magic");
---
>       /*magic_read_entries(mh,"magic");*/
```

It should work then. If not, you will need to adjust the offset into the library for reading by modifying the MAGIC_DATA_OFFSET. If you wish, I can stick up the magic data file into pastebin. Let me know.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I thought about using/modifying libmagic's source too, so I found that sourceforge version as well, but I suspect they're not the same as libmagic-dev from ubuntu repo. If you do `man libmagic` or check http://linux.die.net/include/magic.h, the timestamp is 2003. The one from SF is 2000 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmagic/files/). Otherwise, I imagine this would be a good solution, and I could start figuring out how to pull it off.

Comment: It doesn't look like the `magic` entries from the newer libmagic 5.03 is compatible with the old libmagic alpha. It does look like libmagic 5.03 is included within file-5.03 (from `man file`, ftp.astron.com/pub/file/file-5.04.tar.gz), so I'll try messing around with that. I think I might get stuck trying to do that appending & pointer offset thing, if I get to that point.

Comment: either way, if you need my assistance, please do not hesitate to ask by replying back! ;)

Comment: Try as I might, I couldn't decouple the libmagic part of `file`, nor could I find a standalone source of libmagic. I think I'm just going to have my app identify a file by its extensions and throw if it ends up with the wrong filetype.

Comment: @Kache4: Where is the source for the most recent version of libmagic/file? Will look into it and give it a shot...

Comment: I can't find the source for a recent & standalone `libmagic`, but `file` can be found in http://www.darwinsys.com/file/. Another option I have is to write my own magic number identifier. I actually only need to differentiate a handful of image, compressed archive, and text file types. All I'd need to do once I have an `ifstream` of a file is match a few bytes in the header, right?

Comment: I think a few things might be different. I used `#define MAGIC_DATA_OFFSET <size of clean-compiled libmagic.a in bytes (mine wasn't 38684)>`. Also, what version of file(1) does `man magic` say you have? I suspect this `magic.c` can't parse my `magic` version 5.03 from Ubuntu 9.10. `if (!parse_line(...)) { printf("kache4 added this printf line - parse failed\n"); continue;}` around line 287 fails every time. Btw if this is inconveniencing you at all, I think I'm going to find another way to do this. Getting this to work is just going to be more of an exercise for me than anything at this point.

Comment: @Kache4: Have a look here, I uploaded libmagic_tommieb75.tar.gz for your convenience. http://www.box.net/shared/ao1jzn9ssl

Comment: There's good news and there's bad news. Good news is that I got it to work. The `libmagic-alpha` from SF can parse your `magic` file, but not mine. The bad news is that `minifile` now reads `libmagic.a` for the `magic` concat'd at its end. If `libmagic.a` isn't in the executable's directory, it won't work. I think I'm just going to give up on `libmagic` and try a different method altogether.

Comment: Ok! Oh well, at least you tried...didn't think of that slight flaw..it was fun hacking it though...take care.. :)

Comment: @Kache4: Check this out...http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how to compile a library in statically - you simply pass the path to the .a file on the end of your g++ command - .a files are just archives of compiled objects (.o). Using "ldd fileTypeTest" will show you the dynamically linked libraries - ${libdir}/libmagic.so shouldn't be in it.

As for linking in an external data file... I don't know - Can you not package the application (.deb|.rpm|.tar.bz2)? On windows, I'd write an installer using NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've built self extracting archives. Basically it is a .exe file consisting of a .zip archive and code to unzip it. download the .exe, run it, and poof! you can have as many files as you want.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive