# How to get magic number of a binary file

Tags: unix, file-type, magic-numbers

There is a magic number associated with each binary file , does anyone know how to retrieve this information from the file?

Comment: If you want to write software to support several file formats, just check for the magic number of each format in turn until one of them matches. If you're simply curious, use the `file` command as below and remember that it's neither comprehensive nor bulletproof - there is no standard for this stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [libmagic](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) from the [file](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) package to try and sniff out the type of file if that's your goal.

There are no general "magic" numbers in binary files on unix, though different formats might define their own. The above library knows about many of those and also use various other heuristics to try and figure out the format/type of file.

Comment: Update: on current Ubuntu systems the package name is *libmagic-dev*

Answer (score 10):

```
file <file_name>
```

magic numbers are usually stored in (linux):

```
/usr/share/file/magic
```

also check this link, someone was trying to use libmagic to get the information in C program, might be useful if you're writing something yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The unix file command uses magic number. see the [file man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) for more.(and where to find the magic file )

Answer (score 1):

Read this: http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic

It's complex, and depends on the specific file type you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command which in turn uses a magic library, the magic library reads from a file found in /etc called `magic` (this is installation dependant and may vary), which details what are the first few bytes of the file and tells the `file` what kind of a file it is, be it, jpg, binary, text, shell script. There is an old version of libmagic found on sourceforge. Incidentally, there is a related answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124749/compiling-libmagic-statically-c-c-file-type-detection/2125150#2125150).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Expounding on @nos's answer:

Example below uses the default magic database to query the file passed on the command line. (Essentially an implementation of the *file* command. See *man libmagic* for more details/functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <magic.h>
#include <cassert>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
            std::cerr << "Usage "  << argv[0] << " [filename]" << std::endl;
            return -1;
    }
    const char * fname = argv[1];
    magic_t cookie = magic_open(0);
    assert (cookie !=nullptr);
    int rc = magic_load(cookie, nullptr);
    assert(rc == 0);
    auto f=  magic_file(cookie, fname);
    if (f ==nullptr) {
        std::cerr << magic_error(cookie) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << fname << ' ' << f << std::endl;
    }

}
```