# HTTP content type "application/x-itunes-itlp" using Firefox

Tags: http, upload, http-headers, mime, mime-types

I've a problem with uploading a Microsoft Office 2007 document using [AspUpload](http://www.aspupload.com/) (used to implement the upload form at my website):

If I upload a PowerPoint document with FF3.6 I get a ContentType value "application/x-itunes-itlp".

When using IE8 I get, as expected, ContentType value "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation".

Is this a problem of the used component or a Firefox problem? Does anybody know about this?

UPDATE: Where it's working for Word 2007 documents: both FF and IE gives "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot trust the value of "ContentType" sent by a browser to be correct.  See [section 4.5 of RFC-2388](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) to see what the spec says about content-type.

If you require robust file type detection you will need to use byte-sniffing techniques to accurately determine the real content type. This is commonly referred to as reading the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) of a file. This technique allows you to identify the format of a file independently of additional information supplied by the user.

There are many existing projects that encapsulate this task including [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) and [Apache Tiki](http://tika.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks. "you will need to use byte-sniffing techniques". Such as?

Comment: @waanders Similar [question asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839125/a-solution-to-validate-a-file-type-using-magic-number-in-file-signature-net) about sniffing file types in .NET. (Also updated answer.)

Comment: I did some experiments and found out that the problem in my case is the browser + OS settings. I've tried uploading at 2 different computers with both FF3.6.16 (exactly the same UA), 1 gives "application/x-itunes-itlp", the other one "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation". Thanks for your help, what I've learned is NOT to rely on the ContentType sent by the browser