# Looking for determine file type from the magic number

Tags: c, file, types, magic-numbers

It is possible to determine the file type from the magic number of file?

If I've understood, the magic number can have different size, maybe a reference dictionary or something like a library could help me?

Comment: XP SP3, it will an affect my program?I mean, I want it work on linux too

Comment: Only because I wasn't going to suggest Linux tools if you were on Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get magic number of a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2147484/608639).

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to determine the file type from the magic number of file

yes you can ,because each file format has different magic number.

for example  **FFD8 for .jpg files**

See here [Magic Numbers in Files](http://billatnapier.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/magic-numbers-in-files/)

Answer (score 0):

The **`file`** command on Linux does precisely that. Study its internals to see how it identifies files using their magic-numbers(signature bytes). The complete source-code is available at [**darwinsys.com/file**](http://darwinsys.com/file/).

The following 2 lists are the most comprehensive ones with file-types and their magic-numbers:
 - [**File Signature Table**](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)
 - [**Linux Magic Numbers**](http://www.garykessler.net/library/magic.html)

Comment: Thank you, simple and effective, 
Signature table is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

[JmimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) is a java library for such

Answer (score 0):

Use libmagic (*apt-get install libmagic-dev on Ubuntu systems*).

Example below uses the default magic database to query the file passed on the command line. (Essentially an implementation of the *file* command. See *man libmagic* for more details/functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <magic.h>
#include <cassert>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 1) {
            std::cerr << "Usage "  << argv[0] << " [filename]" << std::endl;
            return -1;
    }
    const char * fname = argv[1];
    magic_t cookie = magic_open(0);
    assert (cookie !=nullptr);
    int rc = magic_load(cookie, nullptr);
    assert(rc == 0);
    auto f=  magic_file(cookie, fname);
    if (f ==nullptr) {
        std::cerr << magic_error(cookie) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << fname << ' ' << f << std::endl;
    }

}
```