# How do I determine if a file is a GIF or webp?

Tags: gif, webp

I have a file that's .gif extension but I suspect that it's a lie and it's actually a webp. What's the best way to know what format the file is?

Comment: On Linux/macOS, with `file BadBoy.gif` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking into file content and checking its [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number). For webp it's `WEBP` and for GIF file it is `GIF87a/GIF89a`.

Here you have list of all magic numbers and where it is located in file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: I used the command here to get the magic number https://stackoverflow.com/a/2147527/60117

Comment: I could probably mention `file` but for some reason (you know, SO is developers' site ;) I assumed you need to do that from your code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html), an application that uses file contents to determine file type.